# Partitioning the parquet file

Tags: apache-pig, parquet

HI I am running pig jobs to process the data and storing the result as parquet file. Now I have to partition that parquet file based on the any of the columns present. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way : PigMultistrorer.

Here is a java UDF that you can register :
https://github.com/saikocat/parquet-mr-contrib/blob/master/parquet-pig-contrib/src/main/java/parquet/pig/ParquetMultiStorer.java

You can pass a specific field as an argument of the multistorer, it will do the partition followinf this field.

When I tested it, I had some performance troubles (very long runtimes), so I decided to use simple multistorage (whithout parquet). It was faster then. Take a look at this link if you encounter the same problem.

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html

Comment: Also i am going to process the data daily and store it in a central location so if I goes for pig it will not happen. Is there any other way like using java

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but you can schedule your jobs with Oozie (http://oozie.apache.org/).Using Java is always more flexible, however it takes longer.